# Optimizing onDraw for many LinearGradient shaders using composite key in HashMap

Tags: java, android, performance, hashmap

I am writing my first Android app (and my first Java app in about the past 15 years). It takes an encoded string and converts the codes into drawing operations. Some of the codes represent gradient definitions, which is what my question concerns.

If I understand correctly, trying to create new objects of any sort during the `onDraw` function (an override in my extended `View` class) will cause lint to output warnings suggesting that you cache objects and never allocate new objects during onDraw. So I decided to try to make a cache of all the gradients defined by the code string. That way if you redraw the same code at the same size, you don't have to re-allocate the gradients defined by that code.

I run into problems when trying to define the key structure for the `HashMap`, which I figured was the best structure for a cache. It would be nice if I could simply use the snippet of code (a string) that defines the gradient as the key, but I don't think that will work well because if the picture is re-sized, the code remains the same, but the gradient has to change size with the picture. So either I can't have the same key for the same gradient of different sizes, or I have to clear the cache every time the picture is resized.

This led me to try to create a composite key for the `HashMap`. Reading up on Java a bit, I find that it doesn't support tuples as value types like C# does as far as I can tell. So the recommended means of creating a composite key was to create a new class. So I start to create a new class to represent the composite key. Then I realize I'm back to square one. If I have to create a reference type object to represent the key, lint is going to give me a warning about allocating memory during onDraw, right? (Or even if it doesn't, I will be allocating memory during onDraw, which is what we're trying to avoid.)

I need some expert advice here. Am I moving mountains for an optimization that is more of a guideline than a rule, and I should just create the gradients as I need them? Should I use the code as a `HashMap` key and clear the cache every time the size changes? Do Strings operations (substring for example) entail the memory allocations I am trying to avoid too? Does Java support custom value types? Do I need to write my own replacement for `HashMap` that can accept a series of value types as a key without allocating heap memory?

Comment: One thing this problem is making me wish for is that there was a LinerGradient.set method like there is a RectF.set method. That would make this much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way (as I'm sure you know), to set a LinearGradient's size or colour. Caching things is what I believe is the best option. So let me just clear some things up:

1. Don't create new LinearGradients every onDraw
2. Yes, substring allocates a new string object (with some minor exceptions being an empty string AFAIK). Since there is no way in Java or C# to actually change the contents of a string object, it must create a new object for the string. This is why this use of StringBuilders is recommended when making strings. Also, it seems like you come from a C# background, so if you haven't run into this yet *(6 months later...*), remember to use `String.equals` not `==`!
3. Java does NOT support custom value types. Everything is allocated on the heap. Hopefully some of the allocations are optimized away but this can't be guaranteed and obviously isn't applicable in many cases.

Basically:

First of all, "lint" is just that. It's not even a warning. It's just a guideline specific to the platform you're developing on. Feel free to allocate on draw, but try to avoid doing it every time. If you need to make a new LinearGradient during a draw, go ahead, but save it for later so you don't have to make it again.

Second of all, there is one special thing you can do with Shaders to avoid making tonnes of them: use `Shader.setLocalMatrix` to move it around and resize it. I've had some troubles with resizing some shaders (I know it doesn't work for RadialGradient, for example), but if you're lucky, it might just work. Perhaps fall back to pushing a new matrix onto the Canvas's stack if all else fails.